# MongoDB replication set without restarting database

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a mongoDB database running in one server. This is its configuration file:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongo.pem

#processManagement:

#security:
security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:

setParameter:
  failIndexKeyTooLong: false
```

I have created a service to launch the mongoDB each time the server starts or each time the database is down.
This configuration is working so far.

Now I have cloned this server into another one. The configuration is identical except for the server IP and the server domain.
This new server is working too but I would like to connect both databases so the new database is synchronized with the first one as with a master-slave configuration.

I think this is the typical case of a Mongo DB Replication Set with 2 databases. But I’m not very expert with databases and after reading lots of documents I don’t understand very much how to do it.
For example, it seems that all options require to turn off master database before making the synchronization, but in my case the master database is in a production environment so I would like to avoid this. Is there any option to configure the replication set without having to restart the master mongoDB instance?

I’ve checked the reference of the replication options in the connfiguration file too but I don’t know how to use them.

In conclusion, is there any tutorial about how to create a replication set with 2 mongodb databases and if it’s possible without having to restart the master (in production environment) database?

Comment: MongoDB replicaset with two database nodes is possible if you have third node configured as arbiter. Without arbiter or odd number of nodes, there is no way have voting so choosing of new Primary. However, I'm not sure if you can have replica set without restarting server(s). https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/

Comment: Thank you for this information. And that arbiter could be implemented in the slave server? I would like to change the production server as little as possible.

Comment: yes, it could be anywhere. master or slave. Arbiter is very light weight so wound't cast much resources. However, it's recommended to have it on separate machine (you can re-use any existing machine) to make sure it's available when in need.

Comment: I've just read in the mongoDb documentation this: "Important. Do not run an arbiter on systems that also host the primary or the secondary members of the replica set.", so I'm afraid I will need another system and I'm not sure I have one available...